# Developing for my client's Apple enterprise developer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, enterprise

i have some doubt to how distributing for clients that have an Enterprise Developer account works.

Here is the situation:
-My company have its own developer account (normal one not enterprise).
-My client wants to distribute an app using their own account.
-My company have to develop this app.

Now, how do i setup my xcode for this? Which solution is the best? Should i use directly the clients account or there is a way in which they add my account as developer in their team?

I'm concerned about this because i'm going to use my company account to test this app on devices during the development and xcode , to me, is pretty hard to understand when it comes to change certificates and accounts.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alessia already wrote the easiest way is to build the app with the enterprise certificate of your customer. For that your customer has to provide you the private/public key pair or give you access to their enterprise program so you can create and download it.

If your customer do not want to provide it to you (maybe for security reasons) there is another way. It's more complicated especially if your customer has no experience with iOS development. In that case you have to develop and test your app with your own developer program. If your release version successfully passes your quality tests you deliver it to your customer and they need to resign your app. see: [example for resign](https://gist.github.com/chaitanyagupta/9a2a13f0a3e6755192f7)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example for resign link is also super useful!!

Answer (score 1):

i think the easiest thing is to make the build with the certificates in enterprise.
So you should ask identity and mobile provisioning created from enterprise account of your client, and then build your app with this certificates.

Your client can also enable (in developer mode) your apple account so you can create yourself certificates (in enterprise).

You can also create multiple target for this management.